# VIM. Sending commands to the terminal?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to configure vim as my primary coding program. I have figured how to compile single files, but when I go to execute the program from within vim, I keep getting a 127 error code. I have `a` aliased on my box to `./a.out`, however when I issue the command `:!a` from vim, it doesn't work. `:!./a.out` does. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 3):

Aliases are defined in rc files that are sourced by *interactive* shell only and work only in interactive mode (vim *does* pass everything to shell, it never executes anything except the shell directly with fork+execve).

By default shell launched from vim starts in non-interactive mode hence `bashrc` is not read and no aliases are defined (though even if they were defined, they won’t be used in non-interactive mode). You may set

```
set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

, then shell will be launched in interactive mode and `.bashrc` file with your alias will be read.

Comment: I have such a highly customized Bash that starting an interactive one takes considerably more time (and prints out additional stuff), that I would favor Amadan's approach of a custom command that duplicates the alias. What's better depends on one's individual config, though.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Me also. Though I am using zsh and even if I was willing to stand the delays `-i` option would start new zsh and `-c` with command part will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Aliases are a feature of your shell (say, `bash`). `!` operator directly executes a file - shell never sees it, and can't do alias expansion on it.</strike> (EDIT: See ZyX)

If you want to make executing your `./a.out` easy, you can do something like:

```
command XX !./a.out
```

then you can do `:XX`. Or,

```
nnoremap X :!./a.out<CR>
```

then a single key `X` will suffice.

Another option (which is frowned upon for security reasons) is to add the current directory to your `PATH`:

```
PATH="./$PATH"
```

which will allow you to run your program with just `a.out` as opposed to `./a.out`. If you then compile your program with (a language-dependent isomorphism of) `-o` switch, you can have it named just `a`:

```
gcc -o a foo.c
```

Given this, `!a` would work. Use at your own risk.

EDIT: ZyX is correct-er. :) I'll leave the answer here for the other information.

Comment: I thought the `!` operator just pushed everything out to the command line. Thanks for the answer. Suppose I'll just have to dabble with key mappings to save my poor fingers.

Comment: Vim never executes anything directly, it always uses shell to execute.

Comment: Why you not just fix the first line? Everything else is true.